# How to ignore some directories but NOT some files inside those directories with git?

Tags: git, gitignore

Please note the following structure:

```
/assets --> this dir shouldn't be ignored. but SOME OF their contents SHOULD.;
ignoredfile.jpg --> should be ignored.
ignoredfile2.gif --> --> should be ignored.
 /blog --> this dir shouldn't be ignored. but SOME OF their contents SHOULD.;
  /images --> this dir shouldn't be ignored. but ALL their contents SHOULD.;
```

Inside `/assets` folder I have a gitignore file with:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
!/images
!/resize
!/blog
```

Inside '/assets/blog' I have another `.gitignore`.

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except those files
!.gitignore
!/images
```

**ISSUE**

When I push to the remote server, git DO pushed the `/blog` directory but NOT the `/blog/images` one. Why ?

How can I solve this ?

Comment: **Why** you want to keep the directory?

Comment: Because the application will return an error IF that directory is not present. However, their contents should be filled with images by the application user, so I do need to have a directory BUT NOT their contents to pass around. The question should actually be: *Why* doesn't git understands empty directories ? :s

Comment: git doesn't track directories, only files; as such, it cannot track a directory that has no files in it; however, you can just create a dummy "``.keep``" file inside the directory, to make sure it is kept.

Comment: @redShadow - Solved. Added a gitignore file inside images as you have suggested. Anyway, omo, it would be so much more convenient to keep track of empty directories as well. :s

Comment: An alternative could be to let the script/application create the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove it from `.gitignore` and re-add it using the usual `git add -A <directory-name>`, and you should be fine..

Beware of merges that might remove the directory again, but if you are merging everything correctly you should be fine.

### Update

You cannot commit empty directories in git; a common way to do that is to put an empty "placeholder" file inside it, just to say you want it to stay there.

For example, put an  empty hidden file named `.keep` into the `/images` directory and change the `.gitignore` like this:

```
/images/*
!/images/.keep
```

now, you add/commit the `.keep` file and you should be fine..

### Alternate solution

Place a `.gitignore` inside `/images`, with this content:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: I've done that. No dice. Please note my question update. Sorry for not mentioning earlier.

Comment: I do actually have several directories that are into the repo, but not their content files. I don't understand why this doesn't work here, and why .keep is necessary. I mean, we do have a file inside that directory, is a .gitignore file, but it's a file that git should track no?

Comment: Forget it please. Looking carefully, I now get that INDEED some file should be present there. I will use that .keep trick. But I'm still confused with those directories. I have on the directory PARENT of the directory images, a gitignore file. Are you suggesting that I remove that file there, and I place a gitignore file inside images folder it self PLUS the .keep ?

Comment: you should be able to place the .gitignore wherever you want, including inside the directory itself; in which case you can use it *instead* of the `.keep`, to keep the directory..

Comment: if that's the case, then can you please check my files structure that I have on my Update 2 op question please, and see what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Solved. I've used and understand your Alternate Solution. Thanks a lot for your patience towards this.

Answer (score 1):

`git` does not track directories. If you ignore all files in that directory, `git` will not record that that directory even exists. You could create an (otherwise useless) empty file called e.g. `.keep` in that directory and `git add` that file, but I'm not sure if that suits your end goal or not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the directory from your `.gitignore`.

Add the directory to your repo using `git add <dir>`.

Commit and push again.

Comment: I've done that. No dice. Please note my question update. Sorry for not mentioning earlier.